# Ideas for a word or term that encompasses humanitarians, environmentalists, etc.

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology

Are there any words or terms that describe all aspects of making the world a better place. Also, are there any labels to describe a person who does?

By making the world a better place I mean aspects like environmentalism, veganism, volunteering, going green, activism, corporate giving, social justice, etc.

Humanitarianism wouldn't cover animal rights and environmentalism wouldn't cover things like food pantry volunteers and animal shelter volunteering. I'm at a loss for an all-encompassing, umbrella term or word.

Comment: If you don't mind the religious overtones, the word _saint_ comes to mind. A second option could be the phrase _model human being_.

Comment: How about do-gooder?

Answer (score 3):

These are idealists.

> noun - 
>   1. a person who cherishes or pursues high or **noble principles**, purposes, or goals.
>   - [Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary, 2010](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/idealist)

Comment: this is growing on me ..., 'practicing idealist' 'benevolent idealist'